# Prove $AB=BA$ if $A^kB=BA^k$ and $A$ positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the linear transformation $A>0$, and for some $k$, $A^kB=BA^k$, how to prove that $AB=BA$

Comment: By positive, you mean positive definite?

Comment: A square matrix is invertible if and only if it does not have 0 as an eigenvalue. Therefore $A$ is invertible, since it is positive definite.

Comment: $k>1$ and $k\in\mathbb N$, I suppose? Just for clarification

Comment: @MoseWintner it just gives AB,BA similar

Comment: Setting $BA-AB = C$ gives you $$BA^k = A^kB + \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} A^iCA^{k-i-1}$$and you're told that the last sum is equal to $0$, and $A$ is positive definite. You want to prove that $C = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to note that there is a polynomial $p(t)$ such that $p(A^k) = A$.  We can simply take $p$ to be the interpolating polynomial that takes $\lambda^k$ to $\lambda$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$.

Comment: **Note:** this also works for $k \in \Bbb Q$, and possible $k \in \Bbb R$

Answer (score 3):

Let $T:M_n\rightarrow M_n$ be the map $T(X)=AXA^{-1}$. Since $A$ is positive definite then $T$ is diagonalizable and has only positive eigenvalues.
Therefore $T^{k-1}+\ldots+T+Id$ is invertible.

Since $T^k-I=(T^{k-1}+\ldots+T+Id)(T-Id)$ then the kernel of $T^k-Id$ is equal to the kernel of $T-Id$. So $T^k(X)=X$ iff $T(X)=X$.

Comment: It should be noted that the map $T$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i/\lambda_j$ for all pairs $\lambda_i,\lambda_j \in \sigma(A)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks.